# BarCode Scanner for GS1-128 format

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, gs1-ai-syntax, gs1-128

I am using Zxing client for developing BarCode Scanner for android.

But I guess it doesn't support GS1-128 format of BarCode.

Is there any other readers which can do it for android?

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: Note that Code 128 is the symbology and GS1-128 is a codification of data on top of Code 128. If your scanner complies with GS1-128 it should be able to insert a start secuence and group separators in the decoded string. Also note that a scanner will read a string not the meaning of every field inside de string.

Comment: You might want to check out GS1-128 Decoder which is able to scan GS1-128 Barcodes with FNC1 characters and decodes the values after scanning. Find it here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.andreashoefler.gs1_128decoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Found the Answer! It does support GS1-128 as it supports Code 128. It's mentioned in the Zxing Home Page itself.
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/